# .Net core 3.1 console application got an error occurred while sending the request

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

I have .Net core 3.1 console application and using the HttpClient PostAsJsonAsync method to call API,
its work fine in my development machine, but when deployed to IIS, I got an error : `"An error occurred while sending the request".`

here's mycode

```
public async Task<string> InsertUser()
    {
        try
        {
            UserModel user = new UserModel()
            {
              Id = Guid.NewGuid(),
              Name = "name1"
            };
 
           var client = new HttpClient();
           client.BaseAddress = new Uri("http://10.70.2.190:5000/");
           client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
           client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
           client.DefaultRequestHeaders.AcceptCharset.Add(new StringWithQualityHeaderValue("utf-8"));
           string body = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(d);
           string signature = GetRSA(body, privatekey);
           client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("signature", signature);
           HttpResponseMessage resPost = await client.PostAsJsonAsync("api/User", user);
        }
       catch (Exception ex)
       {
           Console.WriteLine(ex.Message, ex.InnerException, ex.StackTrace)
       } 
    }
```

some exception was occurred as follow :

execption :

> An error occurred while sending the request

> System.IO.IOException: Unable to read data from the transport connection: A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond.. ---> System.Net.Sockets.SocketException (10060): A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond. --- End of inner exception stack trace --- at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.AwaitableSocketAsyncEventArgs.ThrowException(SocketError error, CancellationToken cancellationToken) at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.AwaitableSocketAsyncEventArgs.GetResult(Int16 token) at System.Net.Http.HttpConnection.FillAsync() at System.Net.Http.HttpConnection.ReadNextResponseHeaderLineAsync(Boolean foldedHeadersAllowed) at System.Net.Http.HttpConnection.SendAsyncCore(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)

> at System.Net.Http.HttpConnection.SendAsyncCore(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken) at System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionPool. SendWithNtConnectionAuthAsync(HttpConnection connection, HttpRequestMessage request, Boolean doRequestAuth, CancellationToken cancellationToken) at System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionPool.SendWithRetryAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, Boolean doRequestAuth, CancellationToken cancellationToken) at System.Net.Http.RedirectHandler.SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken) at System.Net.Http.HttpClient.FinishSendAsyncBuffered(Task`1 sendTask, HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationTokenSource cts, Boolean disposeCts)\

so, I tried to test calling the API with postman and browser on the server but the result was same `"An error occurred while sending the request".`,

then I check my proxy setting on browser and uncheck the `"use system proxy settings"  change to no proxy, and viola I can access the service.

[image: firefox_proxy_settings]

and do the same to Postman `uncheck the "use system proxy settings"` :

[image: postman_proxy_settings]

and it's success, I can access the API from Postman.

so here in my problem is the application still can't access the API.

1. I think I need to add do like `uncheck the "use system proxy settings"` in browser and Postman, in my code.
2. or I have to get the `proxy system` and disable that ?

what 's better solution ? 1 or 2.

I just add some configuration on my web.config :

```
  <system.net>  
    <defaultProxy>  
      <proxy usesystemdefault="false" />
    </defaultProxy>  
  </system.net>
```

but still got the error. and I have no idea to fixing this issue my code.

any please help,
Thank You

Comment: your base address looks wrong

Comment: no no problem with base address, it's only reproduce code.

Comment: As far as I understand that you use system proxy at postman but do not in your code.It seems you should set usesystemdefault to true at web config